# Model with two branches converging to one - zero gradients and constant output

Tags: neural-network, branch

I am building a neural network that takes two different inputs; pictures and a set of numerical features.

The pictures are supposed to go through some CNN architecture and then flatten out, while the features are supposed to go through some dense layers and then I want to concatenate them into a single vector and continue with a few more dense layers.

Before I share the code, I want to say that my combined_network manages to take my two inputs and bring them through the two branches and output a single value. The problem is that the gradients for the combined network zero out completely and the output is ones even right after compiling the network. However, when I check the gradients for each of the two branches separately (without inserting them into the combined model), the gradients are not zero.

Apparently there is some problem with how I created the combined network and I would love some input.

CNN

```py
#INPUT IS [224,224]
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4,padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=[inputs_shape_0,inputs_shape_1,1]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=4,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=2,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.summary()
```

Dense network

```py
feat_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
feat_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape=(inputs_shape_0,)))
feat_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
feat_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8,activation=tf.nn.relu))
feat_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
feat_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,activation=tf.nn.relu))
feat_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.summary()
```

Combined network

```py
def create_combined(model_1, model_2):

  # combine the output of the two branches

  combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([model_1.output, model_2.output])

  # apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the  
  # combined outputs
  z_0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation="relu")(combined)
  z_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation = "relu")(z_0)
  z_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax")(z_1)

  # our model will accept the inputs of the two branches and
  # then output a single value
  combined_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[model_1.input, model_2.input], outputs=z_2)

  combined_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

  return combined_model
```

I also changed my two input networks to the functional API and it still is the same. Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. With network that operates with image data you should use `SpatialDropout2D` instead regular `Dropout`.
2. You not used `Batch normalization`. normally you use them in following meaner:

   Dense -> BatchNormalization -> Activation->Dropout
3. In addition you should add Batch normalization on image data.
4. If after above you still have issues I would try changing `relu` to `elu` or `leaky relu`

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer! I did change the dropout to the spatial dropout and added some batch normalization layers but again, the gradients are fine in the CNN and in the Dense network that goes into the combined network. It's just when I look at the gradient for the combined network that they all zero out, so it's something to do with the code for the combined network. I changed the relus there to elus and it's still the same. I'll try maybe some other activation functions but I think it may be something more technical than that.

Comment: Okay, the issue was with the softmax activation function at the end - very strange! I thought that the sigmoids were supposed to be way worse for the gradients, anyway, it's fine now!

Comment: @Keren if you want to use softmax you should have dense of two. If you have dense of one it should be sigmoid

Comment: Actually, when I changed the softmax to sigmoid, the gradient zeroed out after one epoch and not after a bunch. I've tried many different things, and it always zeros out.. Still have to figure it out.

Comment: @Keren why you so interested in gradients ? your recall precision is not good ? Can I see the gradient calculation  callback ?

Comment: If the gradients zero out, then the network does not learn. It ended up getting fixed completely. I changed a few things but as I previously said, the problem was with the last few layers, and not how I built the two separate networks. 
I changed the last activation function to sigmoid and the ones before that to Leaky Relu, the thing I think that made the difference was the kernel initializer, I changed it from default to 'he_uniform' and did that throughout the entire network, every time there was relu or leaky relu.